# Delete this from a javascript object in a jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, each

I am having trouble deleting `this` (a specific 'event') from  the following javascript object, when `this` is from a jquery `.each()` loop.

weatherData:

```
{
    "events":{
        "Birthday":{
            "type":"Annual",
            "date":"20120523",
            "weatherType":"clouds",
            "high":"40",
            "low":"30",
            "speed":"15",
            "direction":"0",
            "humidity":"0"
        },
        "Move Out Day":{
            "type":"One Time",
            "date":"20120601",
            "weatherType":"storm",
            "high":"80",
            "low":"76",
            "speed":"15",
            "direction":"56",
            "humidity":"100"
        }
    },
    "dates":{
        "default":{
            "type":"clouds",
            "high":"40",
            "low":"30",
            "speed":"15",
            "direction":"0",
            "humidity":"0"
        },
        "20120521":{
            "type":"clear",
            "high":"60",
            "low":"55",
            "speed":"10",
            "direction":"56",
            "humidity":"25"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a shrunken version of the `.each()` loop:

```
$.each(weatherData.events, function(i){
    if(this.type == "One Time"){
        delete weatherData.events[this];
    }
})
```

Comment: You might be better simply emptying weatherData.events (weatherData.events = {}), rather than trying to delete it.  According to one of the v8 authors in an interview I heard recently, when you delete an object's member, the object is converted back to a hash, then back to an object, whereas reassignment within an object doesn't have the object->hash->object performance penalties.

Comment: That sounds like good advice.  I would do that if I weren't trying to save some of the contents.  I was only deleting certain events, not all of them.  I will update my post to be more specific in the opening description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an object where a string (the property name) is expected. I believe you want:

```
$.each(weatherData.events, function(i){
    if(this.type == "One Time"){
        delete weatherData.events[i];
        // change is here --------^
    }
});
```

...because `$.each` will pass in the property name (e.g., `"Move Out Day"`) as the first argument to the iterator function, which you're accepting as `i`. So to delete that property from the object, you use that name.

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/uxucag) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uxucag/edit)

Comment: I feel foolish for not trying the iterator when I even took the time to add it to the function parameters.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need the name of the item, not a reference to it. Use the parameters in the callback function:

```
$.each(weatherData.events, function(key, value){
  if(value.type == "One Time"){
    delete weatherData.events[key];
  }
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/