# jQuery : How do i select an array using jquery selector and remove its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

```
var requiredFields = [1,3,5,7];
```

I am adding my required fields in an array. When i move to next page, i have to empty this array for new set of values. So I want to select this array using jquery and empty the array. Kindly advice.

Comment: `requiredFields = []` doesnt work for you?

Comment: requiredFields .length = 0; Hope this works for you :)

Comment: if you have to use jquery check out the awnser to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10680892/4825796

Comment: @JoseRodrigues it works fine. i can make your response as answer if you add it in the answer section.

Comment: Please never use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
requiredFields = [];
```